# Stop promotion rules being applied in Magento

Tags: magento

In my magento installation I have a complex classification of the clients. On the one hand there are different groups defined. But there are also some clients «VIP», that is a specific attribute (Yes/No).

Now I have some product promotion rules that are being applied to the different groups. But I don't want these promotion rules being applied to the clients that have the VIP attribute set to yes.

For example:
Product A: Regular price - 200€
Promotion Rule: Product A discount of 50€

(note that this is a «Catalog price rule» promotion, not «shopping cart price rule»)

I tried working with the catalog_product_get_final_price, but I can't stop rules being applied with this. It's just a: if ($customer->getVip)... but I don't know where to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i guess you have to edit the properties of the attribute "vip"

go to manage attributes and look for the "vip" attribute. set "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" to yes. Refresh Cache and Reindex. THen you will be able to see this "vip" attribute while making a coupon.

Comment: Hi Sulabh, I already did that and it worked. But I'm talking about «Catalog price rules», where client attributes are not involved.